# How does Google+ embed link works?

Tags: web-development, google-plus

I am trying to understand how does embed link works in **Google+ Stream**.

[image]

I manage a site and usually every post contains some text and at least an image. 
But when I try to embed the link to a certain article on my blog the embed feature does not show the article text and images, but instead it shows the header image of my site plus some other header text content.

Do you know how should I tag or code the article part so that Google+ parser recognize the right thing I want to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a few experiments, it seems that it picks up text from

1. HTML `<title>` tag
2. HTML `<meta name="description"` tag if there is one
3. From the  tag

.. in that order.

Comment: Thank you, I solved filling the meta name description tag.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).